# plotly.js scatter marker size in axes

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly.js

I'm trying to create a scatter plot that will have marker size relative to the axis units.
As I see in the docs, the marker size is in pixels which is not very helpful.

I use this example:

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  y: [1, 6, 3, 6, 1],
  mode: 'markers',
  type: 'scatter',
  name: 'Team A',
  text: ['A-1', 'A-2', 'A-3', 'A-4', 'A-5'],
  marker: { size: 12 } // here I need different marker per (x,y)
};



var data = [ trace1];

var layout = { 
  xaxis: {
    range: [ 0.75, 5.25 ] 
  },
  yaxis: {
    range: [0, 8]
  },
  title:'Data Labels Hover'
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout, {showSendToCloud: true});
```

I've tried `sizeref` for the marker, not sure how it works though.